# How to prove $x = -x \implies x = 0$ for $x \in W$ where $W$ is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Last time I posted a question here, it got taken down because I didn't post the motivation for it. The motivation this time is to prove the intersection of symmetric skew-matrices and symmetric matrices is only zero for my linear algebra class.

As for the title, I have the following so far:
\begin{align}
x &= -x \\
x +x &= x + (-x) \\
x +x &= 0
\end{align}
Where $x$ is a vector. Now, I am stuck because we never defined $x+x = 2x$. If there was only some theorem about a collection of vectors. Also, even if I could do $2x=0$, we have no sense of divide. Essentially, I want to show that $x$ MUST be zero, so that I can show that $0$ is the only element in both the set of skew-symmetric matrices and symmetric matrices.

If you could point me in the right direction I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: $x+x=1\cdot x+1\cdot x=(1+1)\cdot x.$ But the real problem is, as the answer below says, it is only true in a field where $1+1\neq0.$

Comment: You should note clearly, that since the distinction between symmetric and skew-symmetric is removed if the field is of characteristic 2, then it is explicitly assumed that this is **not** the case. In fact, you should assume the scalars are real anyway and so symmetric and skew-symmetric are very different and the proof is essentially the same as long as characteristic is not 2.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Take any field $\mathbb{F}$ with characteristic 2. Then $\mathbb{F}$ is a vector space over itself. Within $\mathbb{F}$, we have $1 + 1 = 0$ but $1 \neq 0$. In fact, for any $\mathbb{F}$-vector space and any $x$, we have $x + x = (1 + 1) \cdot x = 0 \cdot x = 0$.

However, in a field where $1 + 1$ is invertible, we have $x + x = 0$ implies $(1 + 1)x = 0$. Multiply both sides by $(1 + 1)^{-1}$ to get that $x = 0$.

Comment: +1 It should be pointed out that many elementary linear algebra courses define vector spaces only over $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$. This would make the exercise perfectly fine within the context of the course.